# Trying to execute cross browser testing script using TestNG but giving error "FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest Browser(null)"

Tags: java, testng

Trying to execute cross browser testing script using TestNG but giving error "FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest Browser(null) : java.lang.NullPointerException"

Here is my code :

```
public class CrossBrowserTestingFile {
WebDriver driver;
  @BeforeTest
  @Parameters("browser")
  public void Browser(@Optional String browser)throws Exception {
    //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
            if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
            //create firefox instance
                System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", ".\\geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
            else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
                //set path to chromedriver.exe
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",".\\chromedriver.exe");
                //create chrome instance
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            else
            {
                //If no browser passed throw exception
                throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
            }
            }
  @Test
  public void testParameter() throws InterruptedException{
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");
        //Find user name
        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.name("uid"));
        //Fill user name
        userName.sendKeys("guru99");
        //Find password
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        //Fill password
        password.sendKeys("guru99");
  }
}
```

Kindly help with this, TIA.

Comment: Error given : 1. [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.13.1
FAILED CONFIGURATION: BeforeTest Browser(null)
java.lang.NullPointerException 2. SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: AfterTest TearDown
SKIPPED: testParameter
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: How are you running your tests? Can you please let us know ? Is it via a TestNG suite xml file (or) directly from within the IDE by right clicking your class and choosing `Run As > TestNG Test` ?

Comment: Yes, via TestNG suite xml file

Comment: Hi Krishan, When I run project from .java file then it gives mentioned errors, but when run from .xml file, mozilla broswer is launched but nothing proceeds, result view when running xml file : [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.13.1

===============================================
TestSuite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 3
Configuration Failures: 3, Skips: 3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not providing a value for the browser flavor in your `@BeforeTest` and just to ensure that TestNG doesn't complain, you marked the parameter as `@Optional`. So the value for the parameter `browser` in your `Browser()` method is null.

So when Java tries to execute

```
if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
```

you end-up triggering a `NullPointerException`.

You can get past the `NullPointerException` by changing your code to

```
if("firefox".equalsIgnoreCase(browser))
```

for both the conditions. Once you do that, you will then start seeing the exception

```
"Browser is not correct"
```

To ensure that you have a value always for your `browser` parameter, you can do one of the below things.

- When running the test, pass the value of the parameter via the JVM argument `-Dbrowser=firefox` (Yes TestNG lets you pass in parameter values driven by `@Parameters` annotation via JVM arguments as well. For more details take a look at my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2017/09/29/dynamic-parameterization-in-testng/) **(or)**
- You create a suite xml file, wherein you provide the value for `browser` using `<parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>` and then always run your test using the suite xml file.

**Remember:**

`@BeforeTest` is executed ONLY ONCE per `<test>` tag. So if you have two or more `@Test` methods (that reside in child classes) trying to use the `driver` instance that was initialised via one `@BeforeTest` then you might run into `NullPointerException`.

Since you haven't show what your TestNG suite xml file would look like, its hard to comment. I would suggest that you post a new question for that in StackOverFlow.

Comment: As you suggested, I have posted new question with my xml file code : Please find the link for my new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878231/trying-to-execute-cross-browser-testing-script-using-testng-but-giving-error-fa

Comment: HI Krishan, my issue is still open and as you suggested I have posted new question with my XML file code. Link for the new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878231/trying-to-execute-cross-browser-testing-script-using-testng-but-giving-error-fa Please help me with this, If my issue gets resolved I will mark for both the questions.

Comment: @Krishan, can you please check my xml file code, I think it is same as per example given in the link provided by you. (For more details take a look at my blog post here (or))

Comment: @SaketBelokar - How is this question different from what you posted as a new one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878231/trying-to-execute-cross-browser-testing-script-using-testng-but-giving-error-fa). I believe I asked you to raise a new question for the specific part of "facing configuration issues when running suite xml part". Since you didn't specify the mode of execution for this mode, this was considered to be having issues when running from IDE and I have answered that part specifically.

Comment: @Krishan : If I run this from IDE then I am getting 'NullPointerException' and when I run it from XML file then browser is launched but nothing proceeds. So at this moment I am exactly at the stage where I asked the question. And I have already mentioned that my new question is exactly same, only addition is my xml file code.