# Trying to execute cross browser testing script using TestNG but giving error “FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest Browser(null)”

Tags: java, testng

Trying to execute cross browser testing script using TestNG but giving error

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest Browser(null) : java.lang.NullPointerException"

Here is my code :

```
public class CrossBrowserTestingFile {
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void Browser(@Optional String browser)throws Exception {
        //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            //create firefox instance
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", ".\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            //set path to chromedriver.exe
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\chromedriver.exe");
            //create chrome instance
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else {
            //If no browser passed throw exception
            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void testParameter() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");
        //Find user name
        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.name("uid"));
        //Fill user name
        userName.sendKeys("guru99");
        //Find password
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        //Fill password
        password.sendKeys("guru99");
    }
}
```

My XML FIle Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests" >

<test name="FirefoxTest">

<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />

<classes>

<class name="crossbrowsertesting.CrossBrowserTestingFile">

</class>

</classes>

</test>

<test name="ChromeTest">

<parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />

<classes>

<class name="crossbrowsertesting.CrossBrowserTestingFile">

</class>

</classes>

</test>

<test name="EdgeTest">

<parameter name="browser" value="Edge" />

<classes>

<class name="crossbrowsertesting.CrossBrowserTestingFile">

</class>

</classes>

</test>

</suite>
```

Kindly help with this, TIA., This is repeated question with addition of my XML file code. I think xml code will help you guys to answer it.

Comment: I didn't see the issue you mentioned. The script was able to fire chrome and enter the login details. Using `TestNG version 6.13.1`

Comment: Ohh but in my case, browser is launched and nothing proceeds. when I put loggers I found that

Comment: if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){
   //set path to chromedriver.exe
   System.out.println("Reached Browser");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",".\\chromedriver.exe");
   System.out.println("Reached Middle of Browser");
   //create chrome instance
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
   System.out.println("Reached End of Browser");

Comment: Reached Browser & Reached Middle of Browser gets printed and execution stops there. its not creating instance of browser.

Comment: And output shown at the end of script execution : TestSuite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 3
Configuration Failures: 3, Skips: 3